# Google Cloud: Create A Simple Application With the API samples npm install failed

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Following the instruction from here, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api

cd to the samples folder

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/tree/master/samples

The package.json is

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-docs-samples-bigquery",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "Google LLC",
  "repository": "googleapis/nodejs-bigquery",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "repo-tools test run --cmd npm -- run cover",
    "ava": "ava -T 3m --verbose test/*.test.js system-test/*.test.js",
    "cover": "nyc --reporter=lcov --cache ava -T 3m --verbose test/*.test.js system-test/*.test.js && nyc report"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "1.2.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "1.5.1",
    "yargs": "10.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "2.1.3",
    "ava": "0.24.0",
    "nyc": "11.3.0",
    "proxyquire": "1.8.0",
    "sinon": "4.1.3",
    "uuid": "3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I run

```
npm install
```

I get errors

```
    Home-iMac:samples user1$ npm install
    npm WARN @google-cloud/bigquery@1.2.0 had bundled packages that do not match the required version(s). They have been replaced with non-bundled versions.

    npm ERR! path /Users/user1/project1/gcp/nodejs/bigquery_api/nodejs-bigquery-test/samples/node_modules/.staging/@google-cloud/bigquery-78ee5bef/node_modules/@sindresorhus/is
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall rename
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/user1/project1/gcp/nodejs/bigquery_api/nodejs-bigquery-test/samples/node_modules/.staging/@google-cloud/bigquery-78ee5bef/node_modules/@sindresorhus/is' -> '/Users/user1/project1/gcp/nodejs/bigquery_api/nodejs-bigquery-test/samples/node_modules/.staging/@sindresorhus/is-79439449'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent 

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/user1/.npm/_logs/2018-04-27T19_38_14_391Z-debug.log
```

To fix the error, a hack solution is instead of using the package.json to install, I have to run this manually first

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/bigquery
```

Then I can run

```
npm install
```

again. This time, it will finish without problem.

But I would like to be able to just simply using package.json, using **npm install** only to install the packages.

I changed the package.json
From
     "@google-cloud/bigquery": "1.2.0",
to 
     "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^1.2.0",

It still does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I believe you encountered this issue because that sample is configured to use the version of the library on GitHub rather than the released version. I will request an update to the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tim - Thanks for the request to update, @google/bigquery 1.3.0 is being used for the example. The download link to the GitHub site was updated, but the sample code on the page itself is not updated.